# No payment methods are showing up on my configuration screen

Tags: payment-methods

In **System > Configuration > Payment Methods**, when I have Current Configuration Scope set to default or to my website, no Payment Methods are displayed, as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHOTj.png). I have one store setup, and it's grayed out in the Configuration Scope menu. When I select my one store view as the **Configuration Scope**, the Payment Methods are shown, but [the configure buttons for each one are grayed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7D6hp.png).

Am I doing something wrong, or is there an error in my installation? Everywhere I've seen shows that the Payment Methods should show up for the website as they do for the store view. Am I missing a setting somewhere? Thanks!

I'm using Community Edition 1.9.1.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was that my PHP allocation was too low. I discovered the issue by [turning on error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143406/how-to-turn-on-magento-error-messages), and solved it by editing my php.ini file to increase max_execution_time to 90 and memory_limit to 64M.